# How can I display my OSM tiles in Qt client application?

Tags: c++, qt, openstreetmap, mapnik

I am working on a map project and I have an OSM tile server which is built on Linux Debian Jessie and it uses Mapnik and mod_tiles to render tiles.

URL for a tile: http://domain/mod_tiles/Z/X/Y.png

I would like to build a client application too in C++ with Qt framework, but I really don't know how I should start it. 
I found an example in Qt, but I don't know how I could change the tile server from default to my tile server.

If you know the answer or have some helps or if you know another way to solve my problem, please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/location-plugin-osm.html, there are two ways of doing this.
The simplest is to set osm.mapping.custom.host to http://domain/mod_tiles/, then you use the last of the Map.supportedMapTypes.